# What is the limiting behavior of $u_n=A^nu_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A=\pmatrix{\frac 12&0&0 \\0 & 1 & -\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}\\0&\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}& -1 }$, let $u_n=A^nu_0$ for any arbitrary 3-vector $u_0$. Then, what is the limit of $u_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity? I suspect that since the eigenvalues of $A$ are all of absolute value $\frac 12$, the limit should be the zero vector for any $u_0$. Is my argument correct?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ are ${1 \over 2}, 1\pm i{\sqrt{5} \over 2}$, so no, the limit is not always the zero vector.

Comment: My calculation gives that $\frac12, \pm\frac12 i$ are the eigenvalues. Thus the argument in the question should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. As $A$ admits a diagonalisation $P\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac12,\frac i2,\frac{-i}{2}\right)P^{-1}$,
$$
A^n=P\operatorname{diag}\left(\left(\frac12\right)^n,\left(\frac i2\right)^n,\left(\frac{-i}{2}\right)^n\right)P^{-1}\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$ and hence $A^nu_0\to0$ too. Alternatively, as $\rho(A)$ is the infimum of all submultiplicative norms of $A$, that $\rho(A)=\frac12<1$ implies that $\|A\|<1$ for some submultiplicative norm. Therefore $\|A^n\|\le\|A\|^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.